# Allure cannot read the resulting json-file and and the attachment is not attached

Tags: python-3.x, allure

There is such a code:

```
import allure
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from SauceBasePage import *
from SauceProductsPage import *
from SauceCartPage import *

@allure.severity(allure.severity_level.NORMAL)
@allure.title('Removing')
def test_problem_user_remove_item(browse):
    user = StartPage(browse)
    with allure.step('Open start page'):
        user.start_page_open(browse)
    with allure.step('Input data'):
        user.problem_input()
    with allure.step('Login'):
        user.standard_login()
    user = ProductsPage(browse)
    with allure.step('Add product to cart'):
        user.add_product_to_cart()
    with allure.step('Remove'):
        try:
            user.remove_product()
            assert EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'add-to-cart-sauce-labs-backpack'))
        except TimeoutException:
            allure.attach('Remove error', browse.get_screenshot_as_png(), attachment_type=allure.attachment_type.PNG)
            raise AssertionError('Removing failed')
    allure.dynamic.title('Remove successfull!')
```

The code is executed as it should, but after executing the command:

```
allure generate
```

This message appears:
[image]

Continuation of the message:
[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I find error. It's in my code.Шt should be like this:

```
 allure.attach(browse.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="Remove fail" attachment_type=allure.attachment_type.PNG)
```